# Correct preposition to follow "ineptitude"?

Tags: word-usage

I wish to express John's inability to do a certain activity, e.g. cycling, by using "ineptitude" plus a preposition. Which preposition is most appropriate/accepted? "At" + gerund? "For" + gerund? "In"? Something phrasal (e.g. "with regard to" + gerund)?

E.g.:

> Observe John's ineptitude at cycling.
>
> Observe John's ineptitude for cycling.
>
> John is adept in swimming but has a certain ineptitude in cycling.

Comment: _at_ with a gerund or activity name; _in_ with activity name.

Comment: Just me, but I'd go to lengths to avoid using that word.  Why?  No reason.  It just sounds so ugly.  Yes, this is a minority view.  The word seems to have wide spread use.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is "ineptitude in".

This is confirmed to some degree by the following.

[Google ngram: ineptitude in,ineptitude at,ineptitude for](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ineptitude%20in%2Cineptitude%20at%2Cineptitude%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cineptitude%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cineptitude%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cineptitude%20for%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Nice graph. If I had known about "ngram" I probably wouldn't have had to ask the question, ha. I'll wait a bit to see if anybody has better sources but this is pretty convincing and I'll accept it if nothing better pops up.